# New to running loops in Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

edit:
I'm new to running code, I'm trying to run a loop on the command prompt I don't know how to properly execute the loop.  Am I required to make a bash/batch file to get a loop to execute in the command prompt? Any guidance will be appreciated.

I'm trying to take a folder that contains mp3 files and trim the silence at the beginning and the end in all the individual files.

```
for f in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -af "silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-60dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-60dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse" "outputs/${f%.*}.mp3"; done
```

I keep receiving an error that f was unexpected. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See https://ss64.com/nt/for.html

Comment: Keep in mind that "Bash" and "Windows batch" are two different command shells, each having a **completely different** language.

Comment: short answer `for %f in (*.mp3) do echo file %f found` .. if it is in a batch file, double the % signs..  For the *real* answer, follow the link @ReddyLutonadio provided.

Comment: If you are just getting started with scripting on Windows, do yourself a favor and start with Powershell.  Much more powerful, more consistent and easier to understand.

Comment: Powershell example: `get-childitem -file *.mp3|foreach { ffmpeg -i "$_" ...}`

Comment: Ditto on the **PowerShell** recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i do it on powershell. Created a script which removes silence, normalize and inset ID3 Tags

https://github.com/djansen1987/MP3Analyze-Powershell-/blob/93607ed4f9349755df87244675fdfb7adcc019f3/Get-Mp3Details.ps1#L415

In CMD the one liner would look like this:

```
FOR /R  %F IN (*.mp3) DO (ffmpeg -i "%~nF" -af "silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-60dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-60dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse" "outputs/%~nF.mp3")
```

Comment: Thanks, the one liner seems to do the looping correctly on the CMD prompt. So it does what I initially asked. It loops but I get the error of "No such file or Directory". I'm guessing my FFMPEG code is wrong. `FOR /R  "filepath" %F` should point it to the right file path with all the files. Thinking out loud: I wonder since the files contains Kanji's it might not be able to distinguish them in the loop

Comment: Does the output folder exist ? Also try a backsplash instead of a forwardslash `"outputs\%~nF.mp3"`